# PWA - how do I specify a version?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I'm successfully getting Chrome on Android to install my PWA to home screen, using a manifest.json file - I have recently added "version" and changed it from "0.9.26" to "0.9.27" - however, the PWA always installs to the home screen and reports: "Version: 1" - how does versioning work with PWAs? And how do we ensure the user is using the latest version when they open the PWA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know you don't have any control over the version of a PWA generated APK and `version` is not a [supported attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest). It wouldn't make sense for there to be any either since the APK doesn't package any of your app code it just loads the assets from the web.

You control what version of the PWA your users are on by deploying the new version of the site and making sure any service worker you have will update any cached assets.